# Change collection of a mongoose connection based on api requests

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm making a simple api with 2 endpoints that support basic crud on 2 different collections in the database.

My app.js looks like this:

```
const clientApi = require("./routes/clientsApi");
...
Mongoose.connect(dbHost, dbConfig, (error, client) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  database = Mongoose.connection;
  collection = database.collection("clients"); //TODO: figure out how to make both collections work
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "test") {
    console.log("Connected to `" + dbConfig.dbName + "`!");
  }
});
...
app
  .route("/clients")
  .get(clientApi.getClients)
  .post(clientApi.createClient);
app
  .route("/clients/:id")
  .get(clientApi.getClient)
  .put(clientApi.updateClient)
  .delete(clientApi.deleteClient);
```

The goal is to have it connect to another collection, people, with similar routes and endpoints.

That said, the actual implementation of the api is in another file, so I can't just change the collection in those functions.

How can I change my collection?

EDIT:

clientApi example code:

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose");
let Client = require("../models/client");

function getClient(req, res) {
  Client.findById(req.params.id, (err, client) => {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    res.json(client);
  });
}

function getClients(req, res) {
  let query = Client.find({});

  query.exec((err, clients) => {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    res.json(clients);
  });
}

function createClient(req, res) {
  var newClient = new Client(req.body);

  newClient.save((err, client) => {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    else res.json({ message: "Client creation success!", client });
  });
}

function deleteClient(req, res) {
  Client.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    res.json({ message: "Client deletion success!", result });
  });
}

function updateClient(req, res) {
  Client.findById({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, client) => {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    Object.assign(client, req.body).save((err, client) => {
      if (err) res.send(err);
      res.json({ message: "Client update success!", client });
    });
  });
}

module.exports = {
  getClient,
  getClients,
  createClient,
  deleteClient,
  updateClient
};
```

EDIT 2:
The answer ended up being to remove the collection portion from the original DB connection in Mongoose.connect and add the collection to the Schema:

```
let ClientSchema = new Schema(
  {
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    version: { type: Number, default: 1 },
    status: { type: Boolean, default: true }
  },
  { collection: "clients" } //TODO: figure out what this does
);
```

Comment: Could you provide some example code from the `routes/clientsApi` as it seems that you are opening the connection here and then the route handlers in `routes/clientsApi` might be using the models directly to access the database

Comment: @VasilDininski sample code added

Answer (score 0):

As per the code in `routes/clientsApi`:

```
let Client = require("../models/client");
```

you have model defined for the clients collection. You would need to create a new model, for the collection you need to access. For example Products:

```
// models/products.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  price: Number,
});

var Products = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
module.exports = Products;
```

and then in your `routes/products.js` you could use it like so:

```
const Products = require('models/products');

module.exports = {
  getProducts: (req, res) => {
    Products.find({}).exec((err, products) => {
      if (err) res.send(err);
      res.json(products);
    });
  }
}
```

I'd also recommend going through the mongoose getting started documentation as these are some of the starting points on using Mongoose.

Comment: "you would need to create a new model, for the collection you need to access." Yes, I'm aware, and I've already done so. My question was how do I access the proper collection, but I've since discovered I can declare a collection on the schema and it seems to swap the collection automatically. Thanks though!